# How to normalize data in javascript by normalizrjs?

Tags: javascript, normalization, normalizr

I have three objects: categories, subcategories, articles. the relationship between them is by id.

```
const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'category-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'category-2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'category-3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'category-4' },
];

const subCategories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'sub-category-a', category: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'sub-category-b', category: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'sub-category-c', category: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'sub-category-d', category: 3 },
  { id: 5, name: 'sub-category-e', category: 4 },
]

const articles = [
  { id: 101, name: 'article-x', subCategory: 3 },
  { id: 103, name: 'article-y', subCategory: 1 },
  { id: 108, name: 'article-z', subCategory: 4 },
  { id: 107, name: 'article-r', subCategory: 2 },
  { id: 123, name: 'article-p', subCategory: 2 },
  { id: 142, name: 'article-q', subCategory: 1 },
]
```

I'm not sure how to defined correct scheme for those objects. [normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr). I also not sure if this package will be the solution.

The bottom line I need to access the reference object value like that:

```
console.log({ a: articles[0].subCategory.name }); // should output: { a: "sub-category-c" }
console.log({ a: articles[0].subCategory.category.name }); // should output: { a: "category-1" }
```

Comment: you absolutly need to use normalizr for that ?

Comment: Yeah I want to use normalizr or any package to connect between id's.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use normalizr for that..

```js
const categories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'category-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'category-2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'category-3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'category-4' },
];

const subCategories = [
  { id: 1, name: 'sub-category-a', category: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'sub-category-b', category: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'sub-category-c', category: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: 'sub-category-d', category: 3 },
  { id: 5, name: 'sub-category-e', category: 4 },
]

const articles = [
  { id: 101, name: 'article-x', subCategory: 3 },
  { id: 103, name: 'article-y', subCategory: 1 },
  { id: 108, name: 'article-z', subCategory: 4 },
  { id: 107, name: 'article-r', subCategory: 2 },
  { id: 123, name: 'article-p', subCategory: 2 },
  { id: 142, name: 'article-q', subCategory: 1 },
]



function Get_Article_SubCategorie( Art_id )
{
 let sc = articles.find(a=>a.id===Art_id).subCategory
 return subCategories.find(s=>s.id===sc).name;
}

function Get_Article_Categorie( Art_id )
{
 let
   sc = articles.find(a=>a.id===Art_id).subCategory,
   c  = subCategories.find(s=>s.id===sc).id;

 return categories.find(n=>n.id===c).name;
}

console.log( Get_Article_SubCategorie(101)  )
console.log( Get_Article_SubCategorie(108)  )


console.log( Get_Article_Categorie(101)  )
console.log( Get_Article_Categorie(108)  )
```

Comment: Well, I looking for generic solution, like some package do that for me. I do not want to write something that already  somebody else worte.

Comment: Also, Just to use the same object.. I don't want to teach somebody to deal with those objects with functions. I want to be naturally use like : object.ref.name